# How to identify ajax contents (images and text) in a div loaded completely or not when using ajax and jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'show-photo3.php',
    data: 'type='+type+'&count='+count+'&aid='+aid,
    dataType: 'html',

    success: function(response) {
        //alert(response);                      
        $('#vph').html(response);               
        $('#vph').fadeIn("1000");                
        newhight=$("#vph").height();                  
        $("#vph_outer").css('height',newhight);
     }           
});
```

Its for an ajax based image gallery.when i try to re size the outer div based on 
new content's height. its not working properly means take the wrong height.I think ajax contents are not loaded completely when take the height.

Comment: Try to explain your problem a bit more precise. I don't have a clue what your problem is, something about height and ajax. But that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

try calculating height after the animation completes, in the callback function of fadeIn

```
$('#vph').fadeIn("1000", function(){
      newhight=$("#vph").height();   
      $("#vph_outer").css('height',newhight);
});
```

If you have images loaded via ajax, try using [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin before calculating height.

```
$('#vph').html(response).waitForImages(function() {               
    $('#vph').fadeIn("1000"), function(){
          newhight=$("#vph").height();   
          $("#vph_outer").css('height',newhight);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = img_url;
img.onload = function () {
//img was loaded
}
```